# Assign Datepicker on dynamic textboxes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Please find the below code for more information.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
 });
```

This way it will work for all the dynamically created elements of class 'deleteRow'.
 But when it comes to Datepicker initialization How can i do the same? 
 I am creating some dynamic text boxes with class 'datepicker' and i want to initialize datpicker for all of them

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker(); this will work for already existing elements only not for the dynamically created items
```

Comment: For the newly created `text boxes`, you have to initialize the `.datepicker()` method to make it as `datepicker`. Unless it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line you have to put after appending of new row:

```
$(id/class).append(row); // just an example
$('.datepicker').datepicker(); //<----initialize it here when elem is in DOM
```

You have to initialize it when you create new elements.

Or you can initialize it explicitly with `focus` event:

```
 $('body').on('focus', '.datepicker', function () {
     $(this).datepicker(); // this will intialize for current focused .datepicker 
 });
```

Comment: Is any way to initialize at boby level similar to the sample i mentioned fro enable onclick event

Comment: @Jai This will reinitialize the `datepicker()` for existing elements also.

Comment: @JohnR No! That would skip those element which has a css class `hasdatepicker`. it added to the element which has datepicker initialized. if you add this css class `hasdatepicker` to a datepicker element which is not been initialized, if you try to assign/initialize, it just ignores it.

Comment: @Jai To ignore we have to set some condition like this right?
`if(!$(this).hasClass(".hasDatepicker"))`

Comment: @JohnR actually it is not required but one can do it but i would say there is no harm if one don't have any checks because datepicker does it internally.